# To find the differences assingned to a particular name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet below in which I'm trying to find out the difference between ordered products and received products. let's assume we ordered a product name ABC 100 units but only got 80. so when I enter ABC in the balance column it must show the difference(20). maybe we order this ABC in January and received in February, so it might not be in the same row.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d3KTsn-2VPOfcXKulb_HGuk_iXT_hzJ6vxYA61wc-XI/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with `VLOOKUP`s.

1. Some quality of life stuff: use named ranges.

   1. Ordered - Sheet1!C5:D8
   2. Received - Sheet1!F5:G8
   3. BalanceNames - Sheet1!I5:I8
2. In your quantity column:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(
  VLOOKUP(BalanceNames,Ordered,2,0)-
  VLOOKUP(BalanceNames,Received,2,0)
))
```

If you have multiple items in your list and want to sum them, this is similar, but a bit more complex:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(
HLOOKUP(BalanceNames,QUERY(Ordered,"select sum(D) pivot C"),2,0)-
HLOOKUP(BalanceNames,QUERY(Received,"select sum(G) pivot F"),2,0)
))
```

We can use a Query pivot to sum the data. This gives a horizontal range, so it would be best to use `HLOOKUP`.

Comment: @calculuzwhiz..there is an update in the worksheet , I updated here can u pls take a look. simply saying when the product name comes twice in ordered column first take the sum of that product amount then substract it from the same product name in received column. .. please take a look

Comment: @Lizi1990 Ok. Be aware that if you require further updates, it may start to become out of  scope. Use your best judgment.